# Avoiding lost-wakeup when condition update is a blocking function

Tags: c++, condition-variable

I'm writing an event loop that goes to sleep when there's no work to do by waiting on a "work to do" condition variable (`work_to_do`). This condition variable could be notified by different threads based on various events. When an event happens in another thread it notifies on the condition variable, waking up the event loop which then checks the conditions that could have triggered the notify, loops until there's no more work to do and then waits again. One of the conditions is set by a blocking function (`WaitForMessage()`).

The event loop thread:

```
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(work_to_do_lock);
for (;;) {
  if (condition1) {
    // Act on condition 1.
  } else if (condition2) {
    // Act on condition 2.
  } else if (HasMessage()) {
    // Act on receiving message.
  } else {
    work_to_do.wait(lock);
  }
}
```

The thread that handles the notify from the blocking function:

```
for (;;) {
  // Wait for message to be received (blocking). Once it returns you are
  // guaranteed that HasMessage() will return true.
  WaitForMessage();

  // Wake-up the main event loop.
  work_to_do.notify_one();
}
```

The main thread acquires a lock on the mutex guarding the condition variable (`work_to_do_lock`) before entering the event loop, and passes it into the `wait()` call when there's no work to do. To avoid lost-wakeups, the common advice is that all notifiers must hold the lock while updating their condition states. However, if you were to guard the `WaitForMessage()` call with `work_to_do_lock` you could prevent other signals from waking up the event loop.

The solution I came up with is to acquire and release the lock *after* `WaitForMessage()` but before `notify_one()`:

```
for (;;) {
  // Wait for message to be received (blocking). Once it returns you are
  // guaranteed that HasMessage() will return true.
  WaitForMessage();

  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(work_to_do_lock);
  }

  // Wake-up the main event loop.
  work_to_do.notify_one();
}
```

This should avoid the lost-wakeup issue, as it is no longer possible for both the condition to become true (`WaitForMessage()` to return) and the `notify_one()` to occur in-between the condition check (`HasMessage()`) and the `wait()`.

An alternative approach is to not rely on `HasMessage()` and just update a shared variable, which we could guard with the lock:

```
for (;;) {
  // Wait for message to be received (blocking). Once it returns you are
  // guaranteed that HasMessage() will return true.
  WaitForMessage();

  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(work_to_do_lock);
    has_message = true;
  }

  // Wake-up the main event loop.
  work_to_do.notify_one();
}
```

Corresponding event loop that checks new condition predicate:

```
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(work_to_do_lock);
for (;;) {
  if (condition1) {
    // Act on condition 1.
  } else if (condition2) {
    // Act on condition 2.
  } else if (has_message) {
    has_message = false;
    // Act on receiving message.
  } else {
    work_to_do.wait(lock);
  }
}
```

**I've never seen the former approach before, so I was wondering if there was a flaw with the design or a reason it's typically avoided?** It seems that you could use this approach as a general replacement for locking the condition variable lock before the condition state update, assuming that the specific condition state write/read itself is protected by some mutual exclusion mechanism.

Comment: The flaw in your design is that you `condition_variable::wait` without a predicate (and possibly without any timeout). [Here](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-core-guidelines-be-aware-of-the-traps-of-condition-variables) is some article explaining this issue. Then your predicate might be some atomic flag that is set by the workers and you shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: @pptaszni The post you link identifies two potential issues: spurious wakeups and lost wakeups. In my post I describe why I think this design prevents the latter, and as for the former the predicate check is explicit in the `if`/`else if` checks that proceed the `else` where the condition variable is waited on (inside of an unconditional for loop, so they will always be checked before and after the wait). As long as those two conditions are avoided then calling `wait()` is safe (even without a predicate or timeout).

Comment: Well, your example seems to deal with spurious wakeup, but not in a recommended way, which means you still reacquire a lock, go through all conditions and then call wait again. If you can lose the wakeup or not depends on your other workers, if they set the proper flags under lock or not. Worker with `WaitForMessage` looks OK. I prefer to set the (big) timeout to see the error message rather than see my app blocked in case I make a mistake. Anyway, just wait with the predicate and safe yourself a trouble.

Comment: @pptaszni I disagree that this is not a recommended way to deal with spurious wakeups. If you read the implementation source for the predicate version of `wait()` you will see it simply wraps the regular wait in a while loop that tests the predicate function. Your statement that says in my code "you still reacquire a lock, go through all conditions and then call wait again" is also exactly what `wait()` with a predicate will do as well, there is no performance difference. In fact, using the predicate will waste work as I explicitly need to check every condition anyways to perform dispatch.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach works, but it’s less efficient than one which **reuses** whatever synchronization makes it safe to call `WaitForMessage` and `HasMessage` concurrently (or, put differently, takes your `work_to_do_lock` to update the `HasMessage` value rather than (say) using an atomic for it).  Of course, if that’s inaccessible to this code, this is about the best you can do, since you need mutual exclusion for the other conditions.